# Standard way to represent null attribute values in XML?

Tags: xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to represent null XML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774192/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-null-xml-elements)

Is there a standard way to represent null attribute values in XML?

We have an existing XML format that expects fragments similar to:

```
<items>
  <item key="key_goes_here" value="value_goes_here" />
  ...
</items>
```

The original format didn't anticipate the need to distinguish between a null value and an empty string value -- however, that is important (now).

My gut says to create a new format that avoids attributes for nullable values, and use elements for them instead:

```
<items>
  <item key="key_goes_here_and_is_never_null">
    <value xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </item>
</items>
```

That said, I'd rather keep attributes if there's a *standard* way to represent null attribute values in XML.

Comment: How is this an exact duplicate?  My question pertains to null-valued attributes, not null-valued elements?

Comment: This is in no way a duplicate.  Attributes are not elements.

Comment: It's not duplicated. one is for attribute and the other is for element.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about any standard, but how about using

```
<item key="key" />
```

for items that don't have a value,

```
<item key="key">
    <value /> 
</item>
```

for items that have an empty string as a value and

```
<item key="key">
    <value>This is the value</value> 
</item>
```

for items that actually have a value?

Comment: Thanks -- Is there an advantage or expected difference between <value /> and <value xsi:nil="true" />?

Comment: @LemonBeagle: To be honest, I've never seen the latter before, but I'm not much of an XML expert. It seems to me a simple empty tag conveys the message just fine and is easy to understand.

Comment: +1 I'd add you can define this in the schema by making the attribute "value" optional (`optional="true"` I believe).

Comment: +1 -- @LemonBeagle Think of it this way: you want to represent that something is missing (nil == has no value) and the clearest way to do that is not giving any value. Additional syntax is misleading in my opinion.

Comment: We have a similar requirement and we used something like <value /> and <value xsi:nil="true" />, where the former represents empty strings and the latter represents null values.  Also, be careful about using no tag as null because there is a difference between something being null to start off with versus being set to null.  This is especially true when you're sending changes in as part of a request.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774192/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-null-xml-elements provides some examples, too.

Comment: @tjg184: Good point, and thanks for linking this question. This absolutely makes sense.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Although this may have solved the OP's problem, this *does not* answer the question, as stated. Does anyone know how to represent null *attributes*? I do not have the power to change the receiving end, which expects attributes not elements.