# How to handle missing data in xml file?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, csv, nan

I am parsing **csv** files to **xml** files using pandas.

This is how I am currently handling columns missing from my dataframe `df`:

```
if field in df.columns:
    ...
    # Assign a value to the xml element
    ...
else:
    xml_data.append('<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(field_name, -999))
```

So for instance, assuming that column (field) `Diameter` does not exist in my dataframe, the output xml data would contain the following element:

```
'<Diameter>-999</Diameter>'
```

Is there a better way of handling this? **Does the xml format support NaN values?**

Comment: You can represent a NaN as a Null value in different ways in XML. See related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774192/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-null-xml-elements).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, JasonM1. Since I am planning to validate my output xml file against a xml schema, I will go for the xsi:nil format, as suggested in the post that you recommended.

Comment: XML is a data transfer format and doesn't care about the values.  What matters is what is expected by the code that will read the XML.  Find out what that code expects for `NaN` or `null` and provide that.

Comment: Do  not build XML with string. Use DOM libraries like `etree` and `lxml`. See [What's so bad about building XML with string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034611/1422451). BTW - upcoming Pandas v1.3 will have a [`DataFrame.to_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Parfait! I am already using `lxml` to validate my file against a xsd schema. I will check out how to use this toolbox to write a xml file.